# Batch script to return files NOT duplicated with a different extension

Tags: batch-file

I don't have much experience with batch scripting but this seems like a suitable task for it:

I have a very large directory with recordings of a specific extension, say '.wav'. In the same folder, I'm supposed to have, for each of these recordings, an xml file, named the exact same as the recording filename, except with the extension .xml instead of .wav.

Now, I notice that the '.xml' files total count is slightly less then the '.wav' total; i.e some of the xml files are missing.

How can I extract a list of all recordings with missing xml files?

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far? Please share your efforts! Learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! A good starting point is the `for` loop (open a new command prompt window, type `for /?` and read the help very carefully)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.wav) do if not exist "%%~dpnF.xml" echo %%F
```

You don't really need a batch file. You could enter the following directly on the command line:

```
for %F in (*.wav) do @if not exist "%~dpnF.xml" echo %F
```

Actually, you don't need the `~dp` modifiers as I have written the code. But if you include path information like `in (somepath\*.wav)`, then they become important.

Comment: I get an error: "@if was unexpected at this time" ?

Comment: @Maps - Sorry, I had a stupid error. I forgot the DO word that is required in all FOR statements. All fixed.

Comment: I get the same error with @do? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Maps - No, I was just embarrassingly sloppy. I put the @ in the wrong place. It should truly be fixed now. (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

This a little approch can did the trick

You should just change `Set folder=c:\temp` to your folder that contains your files :

```
@echo off
set folder=c:\temp
set ext1=wav
set ext2=xml
Set Log=c:\MissingFiles.txt
set /a count=0
cd /d "%folder%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
    for %%a in (*.%ext1%) do (
        for %%b in (*.%ext2%) do (
            If /I not "%%~na"=="%%~nb" ( SET /A COUNT+=1 && echo "%%~dpnxb" )
        )
    )
    echo.
    ECHO The total number of missing files is !COUNT! 
Endlocal
) > %Log%
Start "" %Log%
```